# Can the Japanese present tense indicate a continuous acton?

Tags: tense

I was watching Shirobako episode 16. and at 2:31 the witch says "落ちる！" as she falls out of a plane. The subs translated it as "We're falling!" but I'm confused on why that is so. I'm not sure if present tense of a verb can be used to indicate continuous action. In this situation, why isn't it "We're going to fall!" instead of "We're falling!" or 落ちる最中 instead of 落ちる?

Comment: I think "we're falling" is a kind of future tense and 落ちる is too.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I've seen in the video:

In this scene, she utters it *on* the plane. Japanese 落ちる usually implies the result of *falling*, so in this case she literally says: "We (our planes) are going to crash!" Maybe the translator wanted to make a more liberal translation.

By the way, the same line is repeated by another woman immediately after it. It sounds like a pun on an editorial jargon 落ちる, which means "an article, episode, publication etc. is dropped, withdrawn with accidental causes" (in most cases, because they were unable to make deadlines).

[image: 新刊落として申し訳ありませんでしたぁっ!!!]
(cited from http://s-c.seesaa.net/article/118641344.html)

Answer (score 1):

Subtitles don't translate directly, word-to-word or form-to-form.

落ちる here is grammatically present tense, but semantically it can be seen as future.

Because there is no "real" future tense in Japanese.

We (are going to) fall!